# Edit text size should not alter the size of Image-view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-imageview

I have an `Image-view` below which, a `Edit text` in a `Relative-layout`.

When the size of `Edit-text` increases by entering any few lines of text,
the size of the `Image-view` is reducing.

**What I want is my text should overlap on the `Image-view` instead of! altering its size.**

any suggestions please.

Note: I limit my Edit-text height and scorllable.

here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.myappp.custom_ui.RoundedImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/selected_attachment"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/caption_holder"
    app:riv_corner_radius="8dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/caption_holder"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_attachement"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/add_captionon_et"
        android:hint="Add caption"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:maxLines="3"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/send_attachement"
        android:textColor="@color/myapp_theme_color"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Can you post your layout code ?

Comment: add some screen shots. desired and actual rendering

Comment: Your image view's dimensions match the root view's dimensions and since the root view's dimensions also match its parent's dimensions, then there is no need for the image view to be above any other view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in using `android:layout_above="@+id/caption_holder"`. It says that ImageView is above the caption_holder, so when caption_holder is resized, ImageView is resized too.

Try to remove this attribute.

Comment: @Bertak ok can I place it below my ImageView?? I want my edittext below my Imageview

Comment: I am affraid that you will need to use fixed margin at bottom of image to have layout looking like the original you posted.

Comment: OR you can add an **invisible copy of caption_holder** (just copy it and change IDs to avoid interferrence with your code) into your layout and make image to be above this special layout (which will never resize). It will deal with different EditText sizes on different Android versions. Just be careful with used IDs.

Comment: Thanks for ur valuble suggestion bro! but even when I gave margin top the gap between imageview and edit text is missing?

Comment: Increase marginBottom on your ImageView, adding marginTop to caption_holder will not work as it is aligned at bottom of parent and it is not connected with image.

Comment: You are welcome. :-) Thanks for accepting my answer.